# Print intersection of two arrays (Java) more efficient

Tags: arrays, intersection

this is for data structure, my professor wants me to write it with efficiency so if he finds one more efficient I'm done lol So... Is there a way to get it without using two loops? (don't use hashtags)

1 loop would be the most efficient

Thanks guys

Comment: "one loop" and no hash set is possible only if the arrays are sorted or have limited range of possible numbers

Comment: Did you try this? http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-and-intersection-of-two-sorted-arrays-2/ **Time Complexity: O(m+n)**

Comment: Hi @Slai, sorry I forgot to say it, they are sorted :)

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek WOW! This is gold! Thanks!

Comment: No problem ;) I posted it as an answer so it could be seen by more people

Comment: well he said that the use of while loop is not recommended (for now, in my course) since it's kind of a little bit more difficult to find it's complexity than the for loop, I don't know how to find the complexity with the while, how is that one that you posted compared to 1 for loop?

Answer (score 2):

Since it turned out to be useful, I'll post it as an answer. Maybe someone will use it too.

Here is the answer: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-and-intersection-of-two-sorted-arrays-2/

And example from the link:

```
// Java program to find intersection of
// two sorted arrays

class FindIntersection
{
    /* Function prints Intersection of arr1[] and arr2[]
       m is the number of elements in arr1[]
       n is the number of elements in arr2[] */
    static void printIntersection(int arr1[], int arr2[], int m, int n)
    {
      int i = 0, j = 0;
      while (i < m && j < n)
      {
        if (arr1[i] < arr2[j])
          i++;
        else if (arr2[j] < arr1[i])
          j++;
        else
        {
          System.out.print(arr2[j++]+" ");
          i++;
        }
      }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int arr1[] = {1, 2, 4, 5, 6};
        int arr2[] = {2, 3, 5, 7};
        int m = arr1.length;
        int n = arr2.length;
        printIntersection(arr1, arr2, m, n);
    }
}
```